# Xampp redirects to /xampp

Tags: codeigniter, xampp

I just installed codeIgniter on my xampp but whenever I try to go to it's folder (localhost/ci) , it instead takes me to localhost/xampp

Can't find what else is needed to do.

Comment: did you set the base url ?

Comment: what else did you edit?

Comment: It's all good, viral was right, index.php from htdocs was overwritting mine. I'm just waiting to be able to accept answer, thanks all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rename `index.php` in your `htdocs` folder to `index1.php`,

then try to access `http://localhost`,

so now you will see Apache's default Directory listing instead of XAMPP homepage.

If you somehow want to move back to the default XAMPP homepage, do rename `index1.php` to `index.php`

Comment: seems to have worked, got some issue with missing the login route now.  I ll figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really necessary to put your codeigniter project in the htdocs folder of xampp. You can also save it somewhere else.
To run it, go to C:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf and replace the line DocumentRoot "/home/user/www" to your liked one.

Answer (score 0):

"index.php" kept in htdocs directory works as redirection.

1. Open this file with notepad or in other editor.
2. At this line:

   ```
   header('Location: '.$uri.'/xampp/');
   ```

   Replace xampp with the name of your website directory name ie root:

   ```
   header('Location: '.$uri.'/bulandshahr/');
   ```
3. Your website will work.